# If condition LEFT JOIN false, how to make it null instead of skip it?

Tags: sql

If condition LEFT JOIN false, how to make it null instead of skip it?
This is part of code:

```
SELECT
    c.Name,
    p.Name 
FROM Category c
LEFT JOIN ProductCategory pc ON c.CategoryID = pc.CategoryID
LEFT JOIN Product p ON pc.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE pc.ProductID = 17;
```

Result must be:

```
FirstCategory SeventeenProduct
SecondCategory SeventeenProduct
ThirdCategory null
FourthCategory SeventeenProduct
```

And so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outer join will give you all records from main table and matching records from joined table. You also want to move the condition from `where` to `join on` condition else the effect would be same as `inner join`

```
SELECT
    c.Name,
    p.Name 
FROM Category c
LEFT JOIN ProductCategory pc ON c.CategoryID = pc.CategoryID
AND pc.ProductID = 17
LEFT JOIN Product p ON pc.ProductID = p.ProductID;
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I would write the query using `p.ProductId`:

```
SELECT c.Name, p.Name 
FROM Category c LEFT JOIN
     ProductCategory pc
     ON c.CategoryID = pc.CategoryID LEFT JOIN
     Product p
     ON pc.ProductID = p.ProductID AND p.ProductID = 17;
```

This is functionally exactly the same as having the comparison to 17 in the first `ON`.  However, I find this version easier to follow.